# Bootstrapping Json TestData in cuba-platform app

Tags: cuba-platform

I would like to create test-data based on cubas Json-Export-Entity feature.

Where is the entrypoint to bootstrapping datas in cuba?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of executing code on starting of an application block is using the `AppContext.Listener`. For example:

```
AppContext.addListener(new AppContext.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void applicationStarted() {
        System.out.println("Application is ready");
    }

    @Override
    public void applicationStopped() {
        System.out.println("Application is closing");
    }
});
```

You can add this listener in any bean constructor or in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

See also the [documentation](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.3/appContext.html).